# how to activated piece of code inside an if statement

Tags: jquery

I've made a simpler example of what i'm actually trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/r5o6cmmd/1/

i want Jquery to change the div's color once `$change = true` however that does not seem to work. could anyone explain why? and how can i do it anyway? (changing the color by pressing a button will not do, i need the color to change through the if statement - only when `$change = true`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$div = $('#div');
$button = $('#button');
$change  = false;

$button.on('click',function(){

   $change = true;

});

if($change)
     $div.css('background-color','red');


});
```

Comment: Upon clicking the button, the only code that runs is the code inside the `click` handler. Your `if ($change)` only run once, and it's before the event is fired. Why not change the background-color in the event handler itself?

Comment: The `$` prefix for variables has no meaning in JavaScript, it is sometimes used by programmers to indicate a jQuery variable. Prefixing a regular variable name with `$` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: is there a way to make the entire code rerun once the button clicked?

Comment: The right way to do it, is to put the `if` inside the event handler. Re-running your `document.ready()` would reset `$change` to false anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test the variable periodically, use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (change) {
        $div.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/r5o6cmmd/4/)

You do not want to change the color upon clicking of the button and yet the condition upon changing of the color depends on the click!! Well, the changing of the color has to be moved to  where that condition changes, which is inside the click handler as below, and there's not need to test the variable because you know it's true. In fact there's no need for the variable unless you need it later.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $div = $('#div');
    $button = $('#button');

    $button.on('click',function(){
        $div.css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

Comment: Kind of silly to test a variable you just set, don't you think?

Comment: No need the condition.

Answer (score -4):

You're missing curly braces for the if statement. Also, if that doesn't fix it...try moving the if outside of the ready function.

```
if (change) {
    $div.css('backgroundColor','red');
}
```

Comment: If there's only one statement in the body, you don't need braces.

Comment: I didn't know that, but that seems like bad practice and might burn you later on in the code. @Barmar

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice, I always recommend against it. But it's not a problem, so this isn't an answer.